# buffer tasks for bulk write to Mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, task-queue, datastore

I am looking for efficient solution for case i have to handle to
thousands of records for saving them to MongoDB database.
i cant lose data but can have delay in saving time.

i searching for the right solution. form what i read i think about:
1. use Redis for caching records and with cronjob bulk insert the records.
2. use task queue for buffering the records and with cronjob bulk insert.
for example rabbitMQ/google task queue - is there a way to set condition consume on buffer length x or time passed from last delivery(like cronjob)

i am using nodejs and mongodb.

tracker schema:

```js
let trackSchema = {
  threadId: string,
  updated: number,//(timestamp)
  created: number,//(timestamp)
  count: number //number of opens
  trace: [
  {
   created: number,//(timestamp)
   userAgent: string
  }
  ]
}
```